# Do UART RX interrupts require support from the transmitter?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, uart, atmel

I'm trying to understand why I am seeing RX interrupts when tying RX to TX of my SAMR34 but not when I connect it to the transmitting device.  The transmitting device notes the following restrictions:

`Serial hardware flow controls (RTS/CTS and DTR/DSR) are not used and will be ignored.  In addition, the receiver must not use software flow control (XON/XOFF)`

I do see data from the transmitter when I poll. Does interrupt driven UART require support from the transmitter?  Should I switch to DMA to resolve this issue?  Here is my setup

[image]

Comment: *"I do see data from the transmitter ..."* -- How do you *"see"* data? *"Does interrupt driven UART require support from the transmitter?"* -- Your use of *"transmitter"* is confusing. Your UART has a transmitter. So does the remote unit. What you call a *"transmitting device"* can also receive, so more commonly it's called a remote device, or the other end of the link. UARTs can generate interrupts for many conditions, not just receiving. *"Should I switch to DMA ...?"* -- If you can't get this to function using PIO, then DMA is just going to make it more complicated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

A UART receiver doesn't need support from the transmitter to generate a RX interrupt. A RX interrupt can be enabled and will generate a RX interrupt when a new data unit (7/8/9 bits depending on settings) is received by the UART.

Serial flow control RTS/CTS and DTR/DSR are in most situations not used and can mostly be ignored/disabled. They have some merit in some situations as noted by Peter Smith [here on electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/253300/221951).

You are probably seeing data when you do a loopback because it is doing everything sequentially and as such will do a `transmit -> receive -> transmit -> receive`. When connecting to an external device the pattern will look like this when transmitting is done in a blocking manner:

```
transmitter:         Transmit Transmit Transmit Transmit Transmit
receive transmitter: Receive->Transmit Receive->Transmit Receive->
```

This will at least result in missing data because the CPU is busy waiting for the transmit to complete before trying to receive another byte.

DMA is used to move data around without involvement of the CPU. And can be used to transfer incomming data from the `IDR` to `ODR`. (Incoming Data Register and Outgoing Data Register)

Another solution would be to have the RX interrupt write the data to a buffer and manage how much of the buffer is used. The TX can then be done on the data without blocking the RX.